# Laravel setting a cookie then redirect to home

Tags: php, laravel

I have a piece of code which should set a cookie then redirect to home, the setting cookie part seems to be missed. What could be the issue?

```
Route::get( '/r/{ref}', function($ref){
    $response = new Illuminate\Http\Response();
    $cookie = Cookie::make('ref', $ref);
    return Redirect::to('home')->withCookie($cookie);
});
```

Comment: You might want search with keywords "laravel" and  "set cookie" on Google before you post this question. Since you are asking what will went wrong if some steps of setting cookies get missed. You should review how to [set the cookie](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_cookie.htm) first.

Answer (score -1):

Change $cookie into [$cookie] and withCookie to withCookies.

Old Code:

```
Route::get( '/r/{ref}', function($ref){
    $response = new Illuminate\Http\Response();
    $cookie = Cookie::make('ref', $ref);
    return Redirect::to('home')->withCookie($cookie);
});
```

Working code:

```
Route::get( '/r/{ref}', function($ref){
    $response = new Illuminate\Http\Response();
    $cookie = Cookie::make('ref', $ref);
    return Redirect::to('home')->withCookies([$cookie]);
});
```